# React Native Icon gets pushed to the end if adding truncate to row

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, layout, flexbox

How to achieve the layout down below in picture? If i take off `flex:1` from my Text than the `ellipsizeMode="tail"` is not working, but if i add `flex: 1` yellow icon gets pushed to the end of container, but it should be next to the Text like in the picture.
[image: layout preview]

```
          <Pressable style={{paddingVertical: 18, alignItems: "center",flexDirection: "row", 
               backgroundColor: "grey"}>
                <Text style={{flex: 1} numberOfLines={1} ellipsizeMode="tail">
                    {longText}
                </Text>
                <View>
              <YellowIcon />
                </View>
                <RedIcon />
            </Pressable>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `{flex: 1}` and no ending } after ellipsizeMode="tail" on your Text. Either reformat it or do something like:

```
<Text style={styles.text} numberOfLines={1}>{longText}</Text>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    text: {
       padding: 50,
       flex: 1
    },
}
```

Comment: The yellow icon is still being pushed to the end. It should be next to the Text

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish that is to use `auto` for `marginLeft` on RedIcon. Something like this would work:

```
<Pressable style={styles.container}>
  <Text numberOfLines={1} ellipsizeMode="tail">
      {longText}
  </Text>
  <View style={styles.yellowIcon}/>
  <View style={styles.redIcon}/>
</Pressable>


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",  
    backgroundColor: "grey"
  },
  yellowIcon: {
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
  },
  redIcon: {
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    marginLeft: 'auto',
  },
});
```

Comment: I still need to add flex:1 to Text to use truncate and again it pushes the yellow icon away. The yellowIcon should be next to the Text and redIcon should be at the end of container